# visual basic - Calling information from one form to another

Tags: vb.net

form1 (login form):

```
Private Sub Login_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login_Btn.Click
    Try
        Dim connStr As String = ""
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from table where username='" & txtusername.Text & "' and password='" & txtpassword.Text & "' "
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While READER.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
        If count = 1 Then
            Query = "select * from table where username= '" & txtusername.Text & " '"
            Dim username As String
            username = READER("username")
            MessageBox.Show( " " & username )

            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct")
            Homepage.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            txtusername.Text = ""
            txtpassword.Text = ""
        EndIf
        connection.Close()
```

form2:

```
Private Sub Homepage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim connStr As String = ""
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from table where username= '" & form1.username.Text & " '"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        If (READER.Read() = True) Then
            Dim username As String
            username = READER("username")
            lblusername.Text = "Logged in as: " & username
            connection.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

OK, the problem I get is, when trying to get the username information from form1, it works successfully the first time. However if I log out, and log in with another username, it would still display the same username? Please can someone help me :)

Comment: Could you please explain what happens to form1 between the time the code runs the first time and a different user logs in? Does it get closed, or does it remain open? How is the information entered in the form1.username textbox?

Comment: I have now included code from form1 (login form) @CindyMeister :)

Comment: It's nice to have the code, but the code extract you posted doesn't answer my questions. I believe if you think through how things work you may figure out the problem. HINT: I see  Me.Hide() in the code: this only HIDES form1, it doesn't unload it or reset it. This means that all the information in form1 is probably still there, unless you have code somewhere that changes it or unloads it.

Comment: I tried to edit a refresh function into the appropriate set of code, however this did not make any different @CindyMeister

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix -.-

```
            Dim Homepage = New Homepage
            Homepage.Show()

            Me.Hide()
```